# Add CC recipient to mail merge Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, mail-merge

I work on an IT service desk and need to send out a regular email to a number of staff however I also want to CC the support email account so the emails end up in our ticketing software.

Can this be done?

Comment: you can put their email id in CC right? i dont see what is the issue.

Comment: The hint is in the title/question. I am sending the emails using mail marge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct option to CC in mail merge but you can take advantage of the rule in Outlook as a workaround:

When you are done with mail merge, go to Outlook and create a new rule to CC the message to people public group.

Then you can go back to the mail merge file and send out the messages.

Remember to delete the rule after sending out the messages.

Here's a video for your reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxcTk3KbpPo

Comment: Any tips on how to do this for Outlook in Mac. I cannot find the cc rule.